# Problema con excepcion laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un pequeño problema con una excepcion, el cual esta con una ruta, por ejemplo.

tengo esta ruta, la cual carga bien.

http://stsroles.test/panel/usuario/create

pero si le hago un cambio como este.

http://stsroles.test/panel/usuario/createrrrr

Me carga un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, en los demas modulos y rutas, si yo hago cambios como estos, me carga la excepcion, pero no entiendo por que para esta ruta no.

Señalo la ruta con la que tengo el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi metodo.

```html
 /**
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
      
        $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);
        return view('usuario.create');
       
    }
```

Archivo de rutas

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/panel', 'PanelController@index');
Route::get('/panel/filtusuario', 'CuentaController@filtusuario')->name('usuario.filtusuario');
Route::post('/panel/gestion', 'CuentaController@ugestion')->name('usuario.ugestion');
Route::post('/panel/bestado', 'CuentaController@bestado')->name('usuario.bestado');
Route::post('/panel/selectord', 'CuentaController@selectord')->name('usuario.selectord');
Route::get('/panel/revisar', 'CuentaController@revisar')->name('cuenta.revisar');
Route::post('/panel/estado', 'CuentaController@cestado')->name('cuenta.cestado');
Route::post('/panel/asignar', 'CuentaController@asignar')->name('cuenta.asignar');
Route::get('/panel/tareas', 'CuentaController@tareas')->name('cuenta.tareas');
Route::get('/panel/inactivo', 'CuentaController@inactivo')->name('cuenta.inactivo');
Route::get('/panel/reportes', 'CuentaController@reportes')->name('cuenta.reportes');
Route::resource('/panel/ecuentas', 'CuentaController');
Route::resource('/panel/registros', 'RegistrosController');
Route::get('/panel/fecha', 'UsuarioController@fecha')->name('usuario.fecha');
Route::post('/panel/selector', 'UsuarioController@selector')->name('usuario.selector');
Route::post('/panel/cedula', 'UsuarioController@cedula')->name('usuario.cedula');
Route::resource('/panel/usuario', 'UsuarioController');
Auth::routes();
```

Se actualiza la ruta para que excluya el metodo show, pero ahora aparece esto.

[image: error]

Pongo un ejemplo, con una ruta que si me funciona, por ejemplo tengo esta.

http://stsroles.test/panel/usuario

la cual estoy llamando con esta ruta, usuario.index, tambien es un metodo de UsuarioController, y si hago esto.

http://stsroles.test/panel/usuariorr,  me carga esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien es un metodo de tipo resource, y funciona bien, se supone que la otra ruta deberia trabajar igual, pero no se que pasa.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu archivo de rutas?

Comment: Claro Emmanuel ya las puse al final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la captura del listado de rutas se observa claramente lo que ocurre:

1. Al escribir /panel/usuario/createrrr, dicha ruta no es igual a /panel/usuario/create, por lo cual continúa explorando las siguientes rutas.
2. La siguiente ruta definida es /panel/usuario/{usuario}, por lo cual Laravel va a intentar encontrar el usuario «createrrr» para pasarlo al método `show()` del controlador `UsuarioController`, según la sintaxis de la ruta escrita: /panel/usuario/createrrr.
3. Por último, el error dice que en dicho controlador no existe el método `show()`, por lo cual tienes dos opciones para solucionar el problema:

   - No está muy bien planteada la pregunta pero asumo que quieres mostrar una excepción, por lo cual debes eliminar el método show del resource para evitar que Laravel siga utilizando dicha ruta:

     ```
     Route::resource('/panel/usuario', 'UsuarioController')->except(['show']);
     ```
   - En caso que necesites el método `show()`, deberás definirlo en el controlador y  replantear tus rutas.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, he aplicado su correccion, pero ahora aparece otro error, es como si mandara por post y recibiera por get, pero solo es un simple get, no se por que aparece asi,

Comment: He puesto un ejemplo al final, de como me funciona una ruta con la excepcion.

Comment: ¿El método show existe en tu controlador? si no existe debes créarlo, el problema no es la excepción, es tu controlador que no tiene ese método.

Comment: @emmanuelhd no es necesario crear el método, realmente depende de como haya diseñado la aplicación.

Comment: Bueno.. creo que la mejor solucion fue crear un metodo nuevo, y dejar de un lado el metodo anterior, pareciera que los metodos tipo resource son un poco estrictos con algunas cosas.

Comment: @Shaz, si hizo su controlador sin la opción `-r` del comando `make:controller` es necesario, por que las rutas las está llamando con `Route::resource` y busca automáticamente las funciones que se crean por defecto (Show, destroy, etc...)

Comment: @emmanuelhd no, no es necesario,  te invito a que leas mi respuesta y a que leas la documentación respectiva.

Comment: Shaz muchas gracias por sus comentarios